# Devise set_flash_message! not working in custom devise controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Because of an api I'm using, I need to take out Devise's registrationsController create action.  I have gotten this to work in every way except one.  For some reason, the set_flash_message method returns the error:

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `set_flash_message!' for #<Users::RegistrationsController:0x007f91f8e8b070>:
  app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb:28:in `create'
```

Here is the controller code:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    def create
        build_resource(sign_up_params)
        resource.save!
        yield resource if block_given?
        if resource.persisted?
          puts "resource persisted".green
          if resource.active_for_authentication?
            flash[:success] = "Welcome! You have signed up successfully."
            # set_flash_message! :notice, :signed_up
            sign_up(resource_name, resource)
            respond_with resource, location: after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
          else
            puts "not sure about this".blue
            set_flash_message! :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}"
            # flash[:danger] = "signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}"
            expire_data_after_sign_in!
            respond_with resource, location: after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
          end
        else
          puts "resource did not persist".red
          clean_up_passwords resource
          set_minimum_password_length
          # respond_with resource
          puts "NOW WE KNOW".on_red
          render 'new' #not sure if this works
        end
    end
end
```

I've put in flash messages the normal way for now but it's already causing some problems.  How do I get set_flash_message to work?

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same issue. Turns out this functionality was recently changed in Devise (January 28, 2016). 
So you either need to update the version of Devise that you use in your app or use the old way of calling set_flash_message, which was:

```rb
set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_flashing_format?
```